# How to change the default audio input

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio

I can get the list of devices using enumerateDevices promise; but how do I change the default of the microphone based on user selection. so in this case how can I make 'Audio 40 USB' to be the default microphone for the client.

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
        for (let i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
            if (devices[i].kind === "audioinput" && devices[i].label.includes('Audio 40 USB')) {

               //devices[i].deviceId ='default'; // make this devaice into default microphone
               // break;
            }
        }
    });
```

I think i found the answer the default will go to

> audio: {deviceId: audioSource ? {exact: audioSource} : undefined}

Comment: You can't change the default audio device, just like you can't change primary screen.  What you can do is capture / play / stream with the selected audio device from within browser JavaScript (with user permission).

Comment: @Sheepy this question was actually about changing input device (contrarily to what the title said), however note that changing the output device is/will be possible too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the "default", whatever that means, since there no real "default". 
When you set the broad `{ audio: true }` MediaConstraint, the browser should first ask the user which audio input device to use from a list (in case there are multiple such devices). At next requests, it is possible the browser remembers this choice and don't ask again.

However, you can very well force the use of a particular device, using the `{ audio: { deviceId: device.deviceId } }` where `device` is a MediaDeviceInfo you gathered from `mediaDevices.enumerateDevices`.

Comment: thank you very much for your respond. I kind of came to this conclusion myself, I have one question; my code above gives me a device Id for one particular microphone , on the same note I go here https://jsfiddle.net/bomzj/beap6n2g/ and run the program on  the same browser, and it gives me different Id for the same microphone. do you have any idea how that could be? also do you know what is extract {deviceId: audioSource ? {exact: audioSource} : undefined}

Comment: Did you unplug & replugged your device? For me it returns always the same deviceIds (as it is supposed to do). And the line you copied is in case no devices got enumerated in the previous step, which sounds quite useless. I'm not sure what part of it you don't understand, but it's just a [ternary operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), could be rewritten as `const constraint = {}; if( audioSource ) { constraint.deviceId = { exact: audioSource }; } else { constraint.deviceId = undefined; }`;

Comment: yes, I just wasnt sure what exact meant, do you know if I can do the same thing for output devices, like the speakers too. Set them into default and keep them

Comment: This answer defiantly works! however the deviceId keeps on changing (not exactly sure when but it happened already a few times to me & my application crashed when trying to set the old deviceId)

What I did instead is saved the user selected label instead of the deviceId & before using it I look up the current deviceId from the label